# When does first print happen in the below haskell code?

Tags: haskell, monads

```
f = do
    putStrLn "1"
    putStrLn "2"

main = f
```

The way I understand `f` reduces to `(putStrLn "1")>>=(\_ -> (putStrLn "2"))`. Is print operation completed while applying the lambda (lifting _ out of monad)? Can someone explain me which part gets evaluated and executed at what stage?

Comment: The `IO` monad is designed specifically to guarantee the evaluation order of side-effecting actions. In general though, Haskell doesn't place guarantees on which part of an expression is evaluated first. The only guarantee is that it will be as lazy as possible.

Answer (score 1):

`putStrLn` is of type `String -> IO ()` so, it makes the computation and then return a `()` in the `IO` monad, ergo the second function that takes that `()` wich is then discarded and then just computes the second `putStrLn`.

The order would be:

1.- `putStrLn "1"`

2- get a `()` as result so

3.- `\() -> putStrLn 2`

4.- `putStrLn 2`

The sintaxis wouldn't be exactly like that, but for you to make an idea.

Comment: Suppose the program were to crash after step 3 would there be "1" on the screen?

Comment: @abhishek Correct. `do { putStrLn "1"; undefined }` prints `1` and then crashes.

Comment: @4castle thanks for your reply. function `f` here evaluates its body and returns a monad to main which main executes. So will not f never return in the above code with underfined inside do block or `>>` will never succeed and thus main will never run and so no side effect takes place. AFAIU only main is capable of side effect?

Comment: @abhishek Because of laziness, `>>` can return without evaluating any of its arguments. When its output is finally demanded, it doesn't need to evaluate its second argument until the `putStrLn "1"` is finished executing.